# How do you invoke windows form property value from another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, properties

I'm trying to close a windows form which currently has the focus from an external thread. Problem is that I can't access the property by simply calling form.Focused which throws "InvalidOperationException: cross-thread operation not valid" as expected. Next I tried to call Invoke on it but it does not recognize Control.Focused as a getter-method. Here's the current code:

```
private void CloseFormWithFocus()
{
    FormCollection openForms = Application.OpenForms;
    Form closeThisForm = null;

    foreach (Form f in openForms)
    {
        // Here's the part that does not compile
        if (closeThisForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { closeThisForm.Focused; });)
        {
            closeThisForm = f;
        }
    }
}
```

However what confuses me is that another nearly identical method which closes a form by comparing to form.Name property allows me to simply call it like this (probably not thread-safe):

```
private void CloseForm(string formName)
{
    FormCollection openForms = Application.OpenForms;
    Form closeThisForm = null;

    foreach (Form f in openForms)
    {
        if (f.Name == formName)
        {
            closeThisForm = f;                    
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked around for different ways to call the property getter but all sources simply state that the compiler should recognize the call form.Focused as a getter and now I'm stumped.

What is the correct way to invoke (or just plain read if possible) a property value of a form from external thread if form.Propertyname call doesn't work?

Thank you.

Comment: The delegate type is wrong, you need `Func<bool>`.  But that is not the real problem, you cannot use Application.OpenForms either, given that it is a fundamental threading race bug.  You need to run the entire method on the UI thread.  Use BeginInvoke() in the code that calls this method.

Comment: @HansPassant Noted, thanks. Probably saves me from a headache later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Focused` property is not "just a getter".

It compares the current focused window with the control's `Handle` property.
The `Handle` property first checks for cross-thread access.
From the source code:

```
public virtual bool Focused {
        get {
            return IsHandleCreated && UnsafeNativeMethods.GetFocus() == Handle;
        }
    }

public IntPtr Handle {
        get {
            if (checkForIllegalCrossThreadCalls &&
                !inCrossThreadSafeCall &&
                InvokeRequired) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.IllegalCrossThreadCall,
                                                                 Name));
            }
```

You can return the value from `Invoke` like this:

```
f.Invoke(new Func<bool>(() => f.Focused))
```

Note: you used `closeThisForm` (while its null) instead of `f`.